# How to convert long long to unsigned int in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

I am reading from a JSON file using jannson library. The key I am reading for has a value that is of type `unsigned int`. Jannson cannot recognize `unsigned int`. So, I am reading the value as a `long long`. How do I convert this `long long` value safely to an `unsigned int`?

Comment: You may not be able to since a `long long` may hold negative numbers and numbers to large for an `unsigned int`. Are you using C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: How do you define "safely"? If the value is certainly within the range of `unsigned int`, then just converting it will be safe.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: "*Are you using C or C++?*" In this case, it doesn't really matter, since they both share the same wording with regard to converting integer values.

Comment: `unsigned int result = static_cast<unsigned int>(long_long_value);`

Comment: @NicolBolas C++ does have other casting options like `static_cast` that C does not have.

Comment: @tadman: But they don't actually *change anything* in this case. If `static_cast` is well-defined, then a C-style cast will be well-defined too. And vice-versa.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not arguing about the well-defined angle, you're right there, but that C++ prefers things like `static_cast` so that bad conversions can be flagged by the compiler. Normally C doesn't care, it just does what's told, where all sorts of ugly truncation errors can and will occur. `(int) floatX` is totally valid even if it produces undefined behaviour for a wide range of values.

Comment: @NicolBolas C++ has other options like `gsl::narrow` and `gsl::narrow_cast` that would be recommended in this case whereas in `C` would be done differently. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863643/understanding-gslnarrow-implementation

Answer (score 4):

> How to convert long long to unsigned int in C/C++?

Test if the value is in range.
C solution:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

// return error status 
bool ll_to_u(unsigned *y, long long x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    return true;
  }
  #if LLONG_MAX > UINT_MAX
  if (x > UINT_MAX) {
    return true;
  }
  #endif
  *y = (unsigned) x;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I think the `#if` is redundant? Even when it is not true the test would still work properly.

Comment: @M.M True, yet some compilers will warn.  The `#if LLONG_MAX > UINT_MAX` avoids that.

Comment: Is <stdbool.h> required for C solution?

Comment: @Myshkin `<stdbool.h>` added.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid narrowing conversion errors it's **safer** to use  - [numeric_cast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html)

numeric_cast is easy to add to project because used boost code is header only - no need to build boost.
This way you can catch exception in case of lost of precision in run-time.

If safety is not the main priority (or you are confident that unsigned int is always sufficient to contain the long long value) than use:

```
static_cast<unsigned int>(llval)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I convert this `long long` value safely to an `unsigned int`?

Like this:

```
long long input = ...
if (input < 0)
    throw std::runtime_error("unrepresentable value");
if (sizeof(unsigned) < sizeof(long long)
&& input > static_cast<long long>(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()))
    throw std::runtime_error("unrepresentable value");
return static_cast<unsigned>(input);
```

You can use any other error handling method of your choice if you don't like exceptions.

Comment: sizeof(unsigned) < sizeof(long long) is known in compile time. It's amazing how checks and optimizations may expand library code. Sometimes errors were found in well-known library functions after many years )

Comment: from the other side it's useful to know K&R strlen implementation for educational purposes.