# How to handle changing data type sizes when porting 32-bit legacy code to 64-bit?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, porting

Our team is in the process of porting a 10+ year old legacy code base to 64 bits (i.e. compile it as Win64 as a first step). Our requirement is that the code both compiles without warnings (at /W4) and that our lint tool (PC-LINT) doesn't complain either.

We get a lot of similar problems, so here I put one as an example:

```cpp
void MyFunction(size_t n) {
    long tmp = n;
    Call3rdPartyApiThatTakesLongArgument(tmp);
}
```

This gives warnings and lint errors about the variable sizes not matching, since `size_t` grew to 64 bits on Win64 while `long` stayed at 32 bits. What we currently aim to do is to bounds check n to make sure that it fits into `tmp`, before `static_cast`'ing it to `long`. This check then gives us another warning about comparing unsigned with signed.
What we ended up with is a huge macro that makes use of things like `decltype()`, `std::make_signed` and `std::make_unsigned` to allow us to bounds check and cast without warnings, and even then we had to disable some lint warnings for cases we knew semantically to be fine.

The function now looks like this:

```cpp
void MyFunction(size_t n) {
    BOUNDSCHECK(long, n) // make sure n fits into long
    long tmp = static_cast<long>(n);
    Call3rdPartyApiThatTakesLongArgument(tmp);
}
```

It really feels wrong to use things like `decltype` and `std::make_signed` etc - is there a better way to achieve what we are trying to do? We're probably not the first people to port a Win32 application to Win64, but our concerted Google efforts have not yielded anything remotely useful...

edit: The signature of MyFunction is not under our control either, so changing n to long unfortunately is not an option.

Comment: It feels like the `MyFunction` should accept `long` to begin with given that it has to call `3rdPartyApiThatTakesLongArgument`.

Comment: @Gserg, thanks, but unfortunately the signature of MyFunction is not under our control either, so changing n to long is not possible

Comment: If you have not control over broken parts of your software you are simply not able to fix it. If you have implicit casts in your code which results in narrowing on some platforms, the code is simply broken. And you tell us you can't change it, what is the question about?

Comment: [This question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5515) may help.

Comment: I assume you have the source of `Call3rdPartyApiThatTakesLongArgument`? Since it's not possible to load a 32-bit dll on a 64-bit process nor link a 32-bit static library to a 64-bit process. Unless you also have the 64-bit DLL and the 3rd party gave you 32-bit non portable headers (Windows' `typedef` helps in making the code portable between 32 and 64-bit). In this case maybe you should either get the 64-bit header or port the 32-bit one. If you have the source instead, I think it's better to start porting from the 3rd party API.

Answer (score 1):

convert from `size_t` to `long` is a narrowing conversion. So there is not a perfect conversion possible as far as I know.

I would convert your macro to a template function. Then you can decide what you do with the error.
You can change your API to long (but I think there it's a reason why it is `size_t`).

So you have to decide what you do when your `size_t` does not fit into `long`.

Comment: E.g. [narrow_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863643/understanding-gslnarrow-implementation)