# Run-time check of integral conversion

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose in the below function:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
bool IsRepresentable(U u);
```

that `T` and `U` are non-bool integral types.

If the integer value of `u` is representable in `T` then `IsRepresentable` should return `true`, otherwise it should return `false`.

What's the best way to implement `IsRepresentable` in C++17? (or is there an exisiting similar function in the standard library?)

(My current thinking was a constexpr if-else chain around `std::is_signed` / `sizeof` / `std::numeric_limits` - but am I missing some easier or more straightforward way?)

Comment: why you need something like that? templates are evaluated at compile time so you should know if u representable in T

Comment: @AhmedAnter: That is not correct.  The parameter `u` is not a constant expression and is not known until run-time.

Comment: @AhmedAnter: `C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer`

Comment: Sorry to typo mistake (T)u==u it will use dynamic cast

Comment: @AhmedAnter `(unsigned int)-1 == -1` is `true`, even though `-1` is not representable as `unsigned int`.

Comment: FWIW there is `gsl::narrow`.  You can read about how it works here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863643/understanding-gslnarrow-implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can imagine, in a simple way, is check if `T(u) == u` and the signs of `u` and `T(u)` are the same

I mean something as

```
template <typename T, typename U>
bool IsRepresentable (U const & u)
 { return (T(u) == u) && (T(u) > T(0)) == (u > U(0)); }
```

Comment: Not bad.  I think you could write it `T(u) == u && T(u) > T(0) == u > U(0)`.  Any reason that would be worse?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos - D'Oh! You're right: works and it's clearer if I can simply check the equality between the two boolean values. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to accepted answer, I suggest You use a [boost::numeric_cast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html). Sample usage:

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c39d5c9e7aed26ad

```
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using boost::numeric_cast;

    using boost::numeric::bad_numeric_cast;
    using boost::numeric::positive_overflow;
    using boost::numeric::negative_overflow;

    try
    {
        int i=42;
        short s=numeric_cast<short>(i); // This conversion succeeds (is in range)
    }
    catch(negative_overflow& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
    catch(positive_overflow& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }

    try
    {
        int i=70000;
        short s=numeric_cast<short>(i); // ad numeric conversion: positive overflow
    }
    catch(negative_overflow& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
    catch(positive_overflow& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```