# How to implement a function that safely cast any larger type to a smaller type in C++ using templates?

Tags: c++, templates, typeid

I'm trying to write a function that checks if the variable being cast can fit in the destination type, and assert() if not. Right now this is what I came up with. I didn't test it yet. I would like to make the template figure out the type of the varible being passed automatically, with something like typeid, although I don't really know what typeid really is. Is that possible? Also, I don't know much about templates.

```
template<typename from_T, typename to_T>
static inline to_T safe_cast(from_T variable)
{
    assert(variable >= std::numeric_limits<to_T>::min());
    assert(variable <= std::numeric_limits<to_T>::max());

    return static_cast<to_T>(variable);
}
```

Well, if that is actually some function that already does this that I don't know of I will be glad to hear.

Answer (score 1):

[C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) already has a `gsl::narrow`

> // narrow() : a checked version of narrow_cast() that throws if the cast changed the value

You can see the Microsoft implementation [here](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/include/gsl/narrow#L28)

> ```
> // narrow() : a checked version of narrow_cast() that throws if the cast changed the value
> template <class T, class U>
>     constexpr T narrow(U u) noexcept(false)
> {
>     constexpr const bool is_different_signedness =
>         (std::is_signed<T>::value != std::is_signed<U>::value);
>
>     const T t = narrow_cast<T>(u);
>
>     if (static_cast<U>(t) != u || (is_different_signedness && ((t < T{}) != (u < U{}))))
>     {
>         throw narrowing_error{};
>     }
>
>     return t;
> }
> ```

You can see the explanation of the implementation [on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863643/understanding-gslnarrow-implementation) (it's for an older version  of the implementation, but nothing substantially changed, so the answer still applies).