# Using gsl::narrow fails

Tags: visual-c++, code-analysis, reinterpret-cast, cpp-core-guidelines

I know there are similar questions and I don't know the best wording for this one.

I find it a little ironic that the reason for the code analysis warning in the first place was that it told me to use `gsl::narrow` into two instances:

Instance 1:

```
auto* pCell1 = gsl::narrow<CGridCellBase*>(lParam1);
auto* pCell2 = gsl::narrow<CGridCellBase*>(lParam2);
```

Compilation error:

```
    6>D:\My Libraries\GSL-main\include\gsl\util(105,1): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'U' to 'T'
6>        with
6>        [
6>            U=LPARAM
6>        ]
6>        and
6>        [
6>            T=CGridCellBase *
6>        ]
6>D:\My Libraries\GSL-main\include\gsl\util(105,12): message : Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Instance 2:

```
auto* pItem = gsl::narrow<NM_GRIDVIEW*>(pNotifyStruct);
```

Compilation error:

```
6>D:\My Libraries\GSL-main\include\gsl\narrow(58,1): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'const T' to 'U'
6>        with
6>        [
6>            T=NM_GRIDVIEW *
6>        ]
6>        and
6>        [
6>            U=NMHDR *
6>        ]
6>D:\My Libraries\GSL-main\include\gsl\narrow(58,9): message : Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Those messages are telling me to do the reverse:

- Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
- Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Going around in circles! Given the situation then, am I to understand that the correct way forward is:

1. Use `reinterpret_cast` and...
2. Add appropriate `prama` warning to suppress the warning.

Correct?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully follow, in particularly about going in circles. `static_cast` is restricted in what it can do (in a way it's 'safe'). Both conversions aren't 'compile-time checked correct' so you cannot use `static_cast` and the error message tells you which casts you can use.

Comment: @MicroVirus In all fairness the **original** code was a C Style cast. And the warning suggested gsl::narrow etc. But I have changed to reinterpret_cast and the pragma suppression.

Comment: Or ... roll your own `pointer_cast` *(vide infra)* ?

Comment: @AdrianMole Myown `pointer_cast`? Never done that before!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (and shouldn't try to) use anything other than a `reinterpret_cast` to convert between a pointer and a non-pointer, or between pointers to different (unrelated) types. The `gsl::narrow` function is just a 'fancy' version of `static_cast`: [Understanding gsl::narrow implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52863643/10871073).

Further, when writing programs that use the WinAPI or MFC, it is virtually *impossible* to completely avoid casting between pointer and non-pointer types; notably, many of the message handling routines take a pointer to some data or other as their `lParam` argument (the `LPARAM` type is defined as either `__int64` or `int`, depending on the target platform).

So, your suggestion is, IMHO, the best option:

> 1. Use `reinterpret_cast` and...
> 2. Add appropriate pragma warning to suppress the warning.

However, you will most likely need to add that `#pragma...` directive in **many** places in your code. So, what you can do is to create a 'helper' (or *wrapper*) cast of your own, which you can then use throughout your code.

For example, you can add the following to your "stdafx.h" (or "pch.h") file (or to any header that is included wherever the cast is needed):

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U> static T inline pointer_cast(U src) noexcept
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) >= sizeof(U), "Invalid pointer cast"); // Check sizes!
    __pragma(warning(suppress:26490)) // Note: no semicolon after this expression!
    return reinterpret_cast<T>(src);
}
```

You can then use that `pointer_cast` and avoid having to add the `pragma` each time. Here's a typical example, using a potential message handler for the `WM_NOTIFY` message in a custom dialog box class:

```cpp
BOOL MyDialog::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    NMHDR* pHdr = pointer_cast<NMHDR*>(lParam);
    switch (pHdr->code) {
        //... remaining code ...
```

---

*Note: on the use of the `__pragma()` directive (rather than `#pragma`), [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?view=msvc-160).*

Comment: Awesome. A neat idea! I am rolling that out across the whole project where I have used `reinterpret_cast`, apart from third part libraries.

Comment: One observation on this one is that the code analysis is now flagging `pointer_cast` saying it can have the `noexcept` word added. Thoughts?

Comment: @Andrew Well, who am I to argue with a code analyser? See edit. :-)